# Wrong label color in gmail 2.3.3

Tags: gmail

I recently created a label on gmail via web, and assigned it a color. On the app on my Nexus S it shows as the default color instead, while all the other labels have the correct color.

I've tried to wait a day, or to reboot the phone; I've also tried to either rename it, or delete it and create it again.

OS is stock Android 2.3.3.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the data for Gmail and re-syncing?

Comment: @MatthewRead: tried, didn't work surprisingly.

Comment: @MatthewRead: also tried creating another new flag, first it had an arbitrary color, then reverted to the default "gray/no color"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed as of Gmail 2.3.5.2.